# jQuery validate plugin require field if another field has a value and vice versa

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validate plugin to validate my form.  I would like to tie several pairs of fields together such that if one field has a value, the other is required to have a value also.  Essentially both fields (both text inputs) must either both have a value or both not have a value.  Is anyone aware of a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which plugin, what code are you working with?

Comment: It's the jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0

Comment: Without code it's hard to say, Why not just combine the two values into one (hidden one) that is processed in the validation?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

if you look at the "rules" section's example code in the [documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate), there is a `depends` field you can set.

something like the following (this is right off my head, not tested):

```
...
secondInput: {
    required: function(element){
            return $("#firstInput").val()!="";
        }
}
....
```

Comment: I was hoping for something that didn't require such a verbose description for each field, but it would seem this is the only option.   I ended up with something similar but I am not using the depends field, just required and it seems to work.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can find the old documentation?

Answer (score 40):

Just for clarification this is what I ended up doing based on Erico's answer:

```
    firstInput: {
        required: function(element){
            return $("#secondInput").val().length > 0;
        }
    },
    secondInput: {
        required: function(element){
            return $("#firstInput").val().length > 0;
        }
    }
```

Each input is now dependent on the other and will only be required if the other has a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate without plugin

```
if ((field1 && !field2) || (!field1 && field2)) {

   // error message

}
```