# Form Validation with jQuery validator having related and exclusive form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have below structure for a form in my project,

```
<form action="somepage">
    <p>Account Number</p>
    <input type="text" size="3" name="accountNumberOne" class="my-form-group">
    <input type="text" size="3" name="accountNumberTwo" class="my-form-group">
    <input type="text" size="4" name="accountNumberThree" class="my-form-group">
    <span>OR</span>
    <p>Email ID</p>
    <input type="email" name="emailId" id="emailId">
</form>
```

The form will be valid if a user fills **all 3 boxes of Account Number** or, **Email ID**. If she submits blank, it will show single error message for both the fields. I know this can be done using **require_from_group** and **groups** property of jQuery validator, but I am not able to implement them together!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide your `js` validation implemented and also link to `validator` plugin?

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ - here is the link to the library!

Comment: Show your attempt at this... do not expect us to code the entire solution from scratch.  As far as the `groups` option, it's ONLY used to lump messages together into one, it's not a validation rule.

Comment: You would implement `skip_or_fill_minimum` with `require_from_group` and separately use the `groups` option to combine the error messages as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple example. It shows a warning message if one of the field as an empty value.
All inputs must be full-fit with some data in order to have the form valid and validation is triggered when clicking the Submit button.

If you want to use a ready-made solution you could consider the flowing plugins;

https://plugins.jquery.com/validation/

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

```js
(function(window) {
  var btn = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]'),
    message = document.getElementById('message'),
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="submit"])'),
    checkForm = function() {
      var isValid = Array.from(inputs).every(function(input) {
        return input.value !== '';
      })
      if (isValid) {
        message.innerHTML = 'form valid';
      } else {
        message.innerHTML = 'warning message';
      }
    };

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    checkForm();
  });
})(window);
```

```html
<form action="somepage">
  <p>Account Number</p>
  <input type="text" size="3">
  <input type="text" size="3">
  <input type="text" size="4">
  <span>OR</span>
  <p>Email ID</p>
  <input type="email" name="" id="">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Not both, either Account Number or, Email ID is required.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make the `required` option `true` for all the elements with a `callback` function as per docs. You can make `required:true` for account numbers if `emailId` field is empty, else you can make `emailId` required if all the `account number` fields are empty. Below is how you can do it.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    accountNumberOne: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $('#emailId').val() == ""; //true only if emailId is empty
      }
    },
    accountNumberTwo: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $('#emailId').val() == ""; //true only if emailId is empty
      }
    },
    accountNumberThree: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $('#emailId').val() == ""; //true only if emailId is empty
      }
    },
    emailId: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $('#accountNumberOne').val() == "" && $('#accountNumberTwo').val() == "" &&$('#accountNumberThree').val() == "" ;
       //true only if all the other 3 fields are empty
      }
    },
  },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refers to the form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
      var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
      $("div.error span").html(message);
      $("div.error").show();
    } else {
      $("div.error").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

## [Here is the DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2h4tvqhj/)

**[Relevant Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406089/jquery-validate-plugin-require-field-if-another-field-has-a-value-and-vice-versa)**

---

**Update**

Make use of `errorPlacement` option to put it in one single place.

## [Here is the updated DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2h4tvqhj/1/)

Comment: Any error messages do not automatically clear themselves until the submit button is clicked.

Comment: Need error messages for Account number parts combined.