# I am unable to validate my form with dates mandatory, for column with values

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to validate my form with the condition that if either credit or debit is entered, the date becomes a mandatory field. And without date, form would not submit.

Please help...i am stuck. My code is:

```
$(function(){
    $("#frmSample1").validate({
        rules:{
          txtCode:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtName:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtParent:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtDate:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtDebit:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtCredit:{
            required:true,
          },
          txtStatus:{
            required:true,
          },
        },
        invalidHandler:function(e,t){i.hide(),r.show(),App.scrollTo(r,-200)},
        errorPlacement:function(e,r){var i=$(r).parent(".input-icon").children("i");
        i.removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-warning"),i.attr("data-original-title",e.text()).tooltip({container:"body"})},
        highlight:function(e){$(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error")},
        unhighlight:function(e){},success:function(e,r){var i=$(r).parent(".input-icon").children("i");$(r).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success"),i.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check")},
        onfocusout: function (element, event) {
         if (element.tagName === "TEXTAREA" || (element.tagName === "INPUT" && element.type !== "password")) {
             element.value = $.trim(element.value);
         }
         /*if (element.debit === "null" || element.credit === "null" && element.status !="empty" // || element.credit !="empty"
          ){
          element.date=$.trim(element.value);
         }*/
          if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
              this.element(element);
          }
       }
      })
    })
```

Comment: That is some crazy complicated code, which AFAIK has absolutely nothing to do with the problem you asked, right?  I mean your question is about validation, not `errorPlacement`? You will make it a lot easier for ppl to help you if you show us only the code relevant to the problem - please see how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery validate plugin require field if another field has a value and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406089/jquery-validate-plugin-require-field-if-another-field-has-a-value-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Hi, i am completely new to coding, and is not much aware of what is enough and what is not,...plz help simplify...